# Natural deduction, true implies something

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Show by natural deduction

$$T \implies (\exists y (y + y = 2x))$$.

How do I begin a natural deduction proof like this?  I am given the premise true, but I don't see how to proceed?

Comment: Proof by contradiction, perhaps? (You'll see what you need to use this way)

Comment: In order to prove it, you have to use the axioms for arithmetic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, which axioms specifically?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction

Comment: Regarding the title, please note that "true implies something" is wrong in general. If "something" is a false formula (like e.g. $0=1$) we have that $\top \to 0=1$ does not hold.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*

We need the first-order axioms for arithmetic; see [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic).

1) $2x=x \cdot S(1)$ --- by definition of $2$

2) $x \cdot S(1) = (x \cdot 1)+x$ --- by 2nd Ax for mult

3) $(x \cdot 1) + x = (x \cdot S(0)) + x$ --- by def of $1$

4) $(x \cdot S(0)) + x = [(x \cdot 0)+x] + x$ --- by 2nd Ax for mult

5) $[(x \cdot 0)+x] + x = (0+x)+x$ --- by 1st Ax for mult

6) $(0+x)+x = x+x$ --- by 1st Ax for sum

In conclusion, by *transitivity* of $=$ :

> 7) $2x=x+x$.

8) $\exists y \ (2x=y+y)$ --- by $\exists$-intro

> > $\top \to \exists y \ (2x=y+y)$ --- by $\to$-intro.

Let $\mathsf {PA}$ the collection of Peano axioms; the above proof shows that:

> $\mathsf {PA} \vdash \top \to \exists y \ (2x=y+y)$.

Answer (score 1):

The expression you're trying to prove is equivalent to

$$(\forall y)(y+y\neq2x)\implies\lnot T$$

Now, to prove this:

$$(\forall y)(y+y\neq2x)\implies x+x\neq 2x\implies\lnot T$$

Note you need to justify $(\forall x)(x+x=2x)$ which depending on what you can assume may be able to just be taken for granted.

Answer (score 0):

*Existential Introduction* doesn't require that all the variables of the expression be bound by the quantifier. Therefore:

\begin{array}{l}
& x+x=x+x & \text{ Identity Introduction }\\
& x+x = 2x & \text{ Addition }\\
& \exists y[y+y=2x] & \text{ Existential Introduction }\\
\end{array}